# AJAX call not work on wordpress - return HTML page everytime

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I currently have a recurring problem with my ajax calls.
I always have the html page that is returned in response.

I'm sending you a typical example that does not work.
It is basically a quiz plugin that I developed and sends AJAX calls at each stage. This call populates a database table.

- Ajax call on plugin front page

```
    var data = {
        action: 'insert_stat_question',
        security : ajax_var.nonce,
        id_formation: $(document).find('#id_formation').val(),
        id_module: $(document).find('#id_module').val(),
        id_question: button.attr('data-id-question'),
        num_question: button.attr('data-num-question'),
        id_user: $(document).find('#id_user').val(),
        statut: statut

    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: ajax_var.url,
        data:data,
        success: function(data){
             // Do your stuff here once ajax response is returned
             //console.log(result);
             console.log( data );
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
    });
```

- Plugin file to list all ajax function and register ajax call

```
    function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/update_stat.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'script-name', 'ajax_var', array(
    // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
    'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
    // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'secure_callback' )
    ));
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

- PHP function call

```
    function insert_stat_question(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'secure_callback', 'security' );
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 
    $wpdb->prefix . 'quizzcreator_stats_question', 
    array( 
    'id_formation' => $_POST['id_formation'], 
    'id_module' => $_POST['id_module'],
    'id_question' => $_POST['id_question'],
    'num_question' => $_POST['num_question'],
    'meta_statut' => $_POST['statut'],
    'id_user' => $_POST['id_user'],
    'date_entry' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ), 
    array( 
    '%d', 
    '%d',
    '%d', 
    '%d',
    '%s', 
    '%d',
    '%s' 
    ) 
    );

    $response = [
        'working' => true
    ];

    wp_send_json_success($response);
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_insert_stat_question', 'insert_stat_question' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_stat_question', 'insert_stat_question' );
```

I try everything but nothing work.

Screenshot of headers and response ajax call:

[image: Ajax Header]

[image: Ajax response]

[image: Ajax header form data]

[image: Complete ajax header with form data]

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [wp_send_json_success](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success)

the parameter should be the array of data you want to send back as response.

e.g.

```
$response = [
    'working' => true,
    'data1'     => 'My data 1',
    'data2'     => 'My data 2'
];

wp_send_json_success( $response );
```

in your case, you can do something like,

```
$action = $wpdb->insert( 
    $wpdb->prefix . 'quizzcreator_stats_question', 
    array( 
        'id_formation' => $_POST['id_formation'], 
        'id_module' => $_POST['id_module'],
        'id_question' => $_POST['id_question'],
        'num_question' => $_POST['num_question'],
        'meta_statut' => $_POST['statut'],
        'id_user' => $_POST['id_user'],
        'date_entry' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ), 
    array( 
        '%d', 
        '%d',
        '%d', 
        '%d',
        '%s', 
        '%d',
        '%s' 
    ) 
);

wp_send_json_success( [ 'action' => $action ] );
```

Also change your ajax request to something like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_var.url,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log( data );
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but unfortunately, not work.

My form data on ajax call:

action:insert_stat_question
security:c539409536
id_formation:7
id_module:164
id_question:203
num_question:1
id_user:58
statut:ok

And response is full actual html page...

It's like if can't access to admin-ajax file or function...

Comment: can you replace your ```insert_stat_question``` function to this ```function insert_stat_question(){ die('Ajax Working'); }```, and see what is the response?

Comment: I edited my answer, the problem might be on your ajax call

Comment: Response return full html page too. 
He does not enter the function but I don't know why...

Comment: change your ajax call to ```$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_var.url,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) { 
        console.log( data );
    },
    error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
});``` I also edited my answer

Comment: I try your change (i update my answer), but nothing happen :-/;

Comment: open google chrome inspect element and go to network, run your ajax call, then you should see ```admin-ajax.php``` added at the very bottom, click on that and take a screenshot of headers and response section and post it on your question

Comment: I update my answer and I saw that there were no data parameters on header.

Comment: below that Request headers, there's also a form data, can you also take a screenshot on that

Comment: I update my answer with form data screenshot.

I saw 302 error on request url : https://ginkorpro.fr/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

it is certainly the problem.

Comment: did you have some redirect configuration on added on the back-end? your ajax request might have been redirected, mostly the case if you have some redirect on the admin and not excluding the ajax request

Comment: I resolve problem ...
I do redirection in other part of this plugin to block administration log where user connect it.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: right, you should always add ```if ( ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )``` or add ```! defined('DOING_AJAX')``` to your current if statement when adding redirect on wordpress admin section,